# How to set the text for range slider label dynamically?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to change the text of this list dynamically:
My code is below:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; width: 320px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 0px; margin-right: 0px; text-align: justify; display: flex; justify-content:space-between;">
    <li id="li0" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">None</li>
    <li id="li1" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Single</li>
    <li id="li2" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Double</li>
    <li id="li3" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Triple</li>
    <li id="li4" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Quadruple</li>
</ul>

<input id="quantitySlider1" class="slider" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="4" step="1" list="ticks1" style="width: 300px; margin-left: 25px; cursor: pointer;" oninput="">
<datalist id="ticks1">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</datalist>
<br>
<br>
```

My javascript part is like:

```
if(sample[i].arrayLevels > 0){
 for (var j =0; j< sample[i]. arrayLevels; j++){
    var tempMod =  sample[i]. arrayLevels[j];
    var tempModName = tempMod.name;
  }
}
```

I want to change the text of list elements based on tempModName dynamically. I only want one slider with this list elements text. I was doing this before instead of doing in HTML.

```
innerHTML = innerHTML + '<ul style="list-style-type: none; width: 320px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 0px; margin-right: 0px; text-align: justify; display: flex; justify-content:space-between;">' +
            '<li id="li5" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">None</li>' +
            '<li id="li6" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Single</li>' +
            '<li id="li7" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Double</li>' +
            '<li id="li8" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Triple</li>' +
            '<li id="li9" style="display: inline-block; font-size:10px;">Quadruple</li>' +
            '</ul>';
    innerHTML = innerHTML + '<input id="quantitySlider' + h + '-' + i + '" class="slider" type="range" min="0" value="' + tempQty + '" max="' + maximum + '" step="1" list="ticks' + h + '-' + i + '" style="margin-left: 25px; width: 300px; cursor: pointer;" onchange="updateQuantityLabel(this.value, ' + h + ', ' + i + ')"><datalist id="ticks' + h + '-' + i + '"><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></datalist><br><br>';
```

Comment: Please clarify... What is supposed to happen as the slider gets moved?

Comment: Suppose my slider is like the slider in this link..
https://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/rOVrGK
So when the slider loads instead of 2days, 3days...I want it to show the value which comes from "tempModName" in javascript.

Comment: Yes, and then what? What is supposed to happen when the slider value is changed?

Comment: when the slider value is changed it should store which one is selected...

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is get the numeric value from the slider and pass that into the array of names as an index to get the corresponding word.

Also, you really should use CSS classes instead of inline styles as shown below.

```js
// Get the list of <li> elements
let wordListItems = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li");

document.getElementById("quantitySlider1").addEventListener("change", function(){
  // Pass the value of the slider as an index to the <li> elements and get the text of the 
  // one corresponding list item.
  console.log(wordListItems[this.value].textContent);
});
```

```css
.sliderLabels {
  list-style-type: none; 
  width: 320px; 
  margin-bottom: 0px; 
  padding-left: 25px; 
  padding-right: 0px; 
  margin-right: 0px; 
  text-align: justify; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.slider {
  width: 300px; 
  margin-left: 25px; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block; 
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sliderLabels">
    <li id="li0">None</li>
    <li id="li1">Single</li>
    <li id="li2">Double</li>
    <li id="li3">Triple</li>
    <li id="li4">Quadruple</li>
</ul>

<input id="quantitySlider1" class="slider" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="4" list="ticks1">
<datalist id="ticks1">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: hey, when I do this " var tempModName = tempMod.name;" I get tempModName as "Extra, Lite,...". I want to set the text of that slider in that way instead of None, Single,...

Comment: You really need to clarify all of this because now you are confusing me. Where do the words `Extra, Lite....` come from? I don't see anything like that in your code. Also, you are back to saying that you want to "set the text of that slider", when earlier you said you want to "get the text of the selected slider item". Which is it? Please be clear and complete as to what you are looking for.

Comment: You've also got `sample[i].arrayLevels` in your code, but haven't shown where that gets its value from.